# Enabling Single Sign On in TEdgeBrowser

Tags: delphi, single-sign-on, delphi-11-alexandria, tedgebrowser

I have some C# code that shows how to enable Single Sign On in WebView2.

The TEdgeBrowser doesn't expose any of the properties that the C# code uses. In particular the interface defined in the Winapi.WebView2 unit for ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions doesn't have the functions for getting or setting AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount defined in it. I believe that this is because it was created from WebView2.tlb on 07/05/2020 whereas the property was added in the version released September 10, 2020.

What options do I have? Do I need to create my own version of WebView2 from the latest tlb and then duplicate the code in the Vcl.Edge unit to get a component with the SSO option enabled?

I don't need a visual component - I'd be happy to create the browser in code.

The C# code is:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var browser = new WebView2();

  var options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();
  options.AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount = true;

  var environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(options: options).ConfigureAwait(false);

  await browser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(environment).ConfigureAwait(false);

  Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
  {
      browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      this.Controls.Add(browser);
      browser.Source = new Uri(https://example.com);
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [WebView4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/WebView4Delphi) instead. WebView4Delphi is fully updated to the latest WebView2 version and it supports all the WebView2 interfaces.

You only have to add this line before the GlobalWebView2Loader.StartWebView2 call :

```
GlobalWebView2Loader.AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount := True;
```

The demos use the initialization section of the main unit to create GlobalWebView2Loader and set the properties. If you use the SimpleBrowser demo as a template for your application then you would have to add the previous line [here](https://github.com/salvadordf/WebView4Delphi/blob/c56f656133ca3aba0dc1486df7765833aa2f0844/demos/Delphi_VCL/SimpleBrowser/uSimpleBrowser.pas#L130).

That property in GlobalWebView2Loader is used for all the browsers that share the same ICoreWebView2Environment which is the default behavior.

In case you need to create a browser with an independent ICoreWebView2Environment then you have to set this property before the TWVBrowserBase.CreateBrowser call :

```
MyWVBrowser.AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount := True;
```

MyWVBrowser would be an instance of TWVBrowser.